# Distorting a UV map for vacuum forming

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

For my graduation project in design university I'm working with the technique of vacuum forming.
My goal is to be able to physically print an image onto a sheet of plastics and then form this sheet of plastic over a mold (for instance a face). Like described in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKHb1hBS7bY&index=57&list=PLhQgkDdtdogQNrsdQWNkaNwtS8ROL_PdF&t=3s

The problem is that the plastic sheet does not equally deform everywhere so the image that im using needs to be pre-distorted according to the deformation of the plastic.
My plan to solve this problem is to first print a grid on a sheet of plastic and form this over the mold so I have an idea of how the plastic is deforming. I could then 3D scan this formed piece of plastic with the grid on top. 
But then my question is: How do I figure out how to deform my original texture so it fits the face perfectly when I vacuum form it?
Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT 2:

I made a more comprehensible overview of the steps I made to obtain the deformed image. See added picture.

Step 1:
I drew a grid on a piece of plastic.
I vacuum formed this plastic sheet over the clock so now I now the deformation of the sheet of plastic

Step 2:
I 3D scan the sheet with the grid

Step 3:
I remodel the geometry of the clock and overlap the faces with the deformed squares of the scan

Step 4:
I 3D scan the original clock

Step 5: 
I bake the textures from the scan of the original clock on the model I made in step 3

Does anyone now have an idea how I can take the newly baked texture and deform it so it matches the undeformed grid I drew on the plastic sheet?

[image]

Comment: Please describe the approach yourself, instead of expecting people to watch a video.

Comment: Honestly I feel like I'd be doing your graduation project if I answered this.

Comment: It does feel like we are doing your project for you. Anyway. hard to follow all this without images to back it up, but sounds like you should trace a grid mesh over your image of the deformed grid so it follows this distortion. Then you can cleanly unwrap it over the image and texture it. If now you straighten your 3D mesh it will yield the distorted image

Comment: Thanks for your reaction Duarte, I realize that it is quite a complicated question I'm asking. I will work on what you have told me now and then try to formulate my question more clearly with pictures of what I have already done.